# Is there a way I could refactor this Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I want to refactor this code so I can put the whole DB query logic in a different file and just call only the function in this file, how would I go about that?

```
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
       clientID: googleId,
       clientSecret: clientSecret,
       callbackURL: 'http://localhost:5000/auth/google/callback',
      
    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)=> {
         User.findOne({googleid:profile.id}).then((currentUser)=>{
             if(currentUser){
                 console.log(`current User: ${currentUser}`)
                 done(null,currentUser)
             }else{
                new User ({
                    name:profile.displayName,
                    googleid:profile.id
                }).save().then((user) => {console.log(`newly created user: ${user}`); done(null, user)})
             }
         })
       
         
      })
    )
```

Comment: NodeJS applications use modules to separate code based upon the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the database code in a separate module where you export a function to use in the strategy and then this strategy file can import that function and use it here in the `GoogleStrategy` implementation.

This is how modules are used in nodejs to organize code.

Here's one way you could separate out the code:

```
import { processUser } from "./db-helper.js";

passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: googleId,
        clientSecret: clientSecret,
        callbackURL: 'http://localhost:5000/auth/google/callback',

    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        processUser(profile).then(user => {
            done(null, user);
        }).catch(done);
    });
);
```

And, then in db-helper.js

```
export async function processUser(profile) {
    const currentUser = await User.findOne({ googleid: profile.id });
    if (currentUser) {
        console.log(`current User: ${currentUser}`)
        return currentUser;
    } else {
        const user = await new User({
            name: profile.displayName,
            googleid: profile.id
        }).save();
        console.log(`newly created user: ${user}`);
        return user;
    }
}
```